# setsockopt SO_BROADCAST on TCP socket

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, posix, setsockopt

In an existing networking library I've been tasked to work on there is a call to `setsockopt` which I don't understand

Here you can see a TCP socket begin created:

```
[socket] fd(11) domain(2:AF_INET) type(1:SOCK_STREAM) protocol(0:default)
```

Immediately afterward, a call to `setsockopt` is made for option `SO_BROADCAST` at the `IPPROTO_TCP` protocol level, with option value `5`

```
[setsockopt] fd(11) level(6:IPPROTO_TCP) option(6:SO_BROADCAST) ret(0) option:
    0    0500 0000                                  ....
```

According to [Beej's guide to networking](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/setsockoptman.html) this *"Does nothing—NOTHING!!—to TCP stream sockets! Hahaha!"*

**Questions:**

- What exactly are they doing here?
- Does this make any sense?
- If anything, surely it should be `option_value=1`, so what is the `5` about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your setsockopt decoder is wrong. Are you sure it isn't one of these?

```
#define TCP_NODELAY              1  /* Don't delay send to coalesce packets  */
#define TCP_MAXSEG               2  /* Set maximum segment size  */
#define TCP_CORK                 3  /* Control sending of partial frames  */
#define TCP_KEEPIDLE             4  /* Start keeplives after this period */
#define TCP_KEEPINTVL            5  /* Interval between keepalives */
#define TCP_KEEPCNT              6  /* Number of keepalives before death */
```

That isn't a full list. See /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h for everything.

Comment: Ah yes - I suppose it should be given `level=6` right? Thanks!